# Prove that $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \sqrt{x + \sqrt{ x + \sqrt{x}}} }{\sqrt[8]{x}}= 1$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Prove that $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \sqrt{x + \sqrt{ x + \sqrt{x}}} }{\sqrt[8]{x}}= 1$$

Let $x=y^8$ with $t>0$. Then after we get 
$$
\lim \frac{ \sqrt { t^8 + \sqrt{ t^8 + \sqrt{t^8}}}}{ t} = \lim \frac{ \sqrt{ t^8 + \sqrt{ t^8 + t^4}}}{ t}
$$
  and can't go further than that

Comment: Have you tried L'hopital's rule?

Comment: Can't use L'hopital's rule as we haven't yet learned it yet

Comment: Maybe you could take $t^8 + t^4 = t^4(t^4+1)$ and see where that leads you.

Comment: It worked thanks

Comment: When $x$ tends to zero, $x$ becomes negligible in front of $\sqrt x$, so that the numerator is essentially $\sqrt[8]x$.

Comment: $$ \frac{ \sqrt { t^8 + \sqrt{ t^8 + \sqrt{t^8}}}}{ t}=  \sqrt {\frac{t^8}{t^2} + \sqrt{\frac{t^8}{t^4} + \sqrt{\frac{t^8}{t^8}}}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$ \frac{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{ x + \sqrt x}}}{\sqrt[8] x} = \frac{ \sqrt{x + \sqrt[4] x\sqrt{ \frac{x}{ \sqrt x}+1}}}{\sqrt[8] x} = \frac{\sqrt[8]x\sqrt{\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]x} + \sqrt{ \frac{x}{ \sqrt x}+1}}}{\sqrt[8] x} =$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]x} + \sqrt{ \frac{x}{ \sqrt x}+1}} \to \sqrt{0 + \sqrt{ 0+1}}=1$$

or in a similar way by your approach

$$\frac{ \sqrt{ t^8 + \sqrt{ t^8 + t^4}}}{ t}=\frac{ \sqrt{ t^8 + t^2\sqrt{ t^4 + 1}}}{ t}=\frac{ t\sqrt{ t^6 + \sqrt{ t^4 + 1}}}{ t}=\sqrt{ t^6 + \sqrt{ t^4 + 1}} \to 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Numerator :

$((t^2)^4+t^2(1+t^4)^{1/2})^{1/2}=$

$t(t^6+(1+t^4)^{1/2})^{1/2}$;

1) $f(t):=(1+t^4)^{1/2};$

2) $g(t):=t^6;$

3)$ h(t):= (g(t)+f(t))^{1/2}:$

4) $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} h(t)=$

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}(g(t)+f(t))^{1/2}$;

All functions $g, f, √$ are continuos.

Hence?